# Is $\mathcal O(n,\mathbb C)$ Compact?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I know that $\mathcal O (n,\mathbb R)$ is compact. One can prove easily by using the continuous map $det(A),$ and norm is bounded.  By Heine -Borel theorem it is compact. But I got stuck to prove it for $\mathcal O(n,\mathbb C).$ What special about $\mathbb C?$ I know all the basic properties of compactness. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't $GL(1, \Bbb R) = \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$? Do you perhaps mean $SL$ instead of $GL$?

Comment: That doesn't matter.  $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an open set in the set of all matrices, so it cannot be compact by Heine-Borel.

Comment: Sorry, extremely sorry. It will be $\mathcal O(n,\mathbb C)$. I apologize to all of you.

Comment: From the definition it is quite obvious the complex orthogonal group is a non-compact complex Lie group, the unitary group is a compact real Lie group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$O(n,\mathbb{C})\subset\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is an affine algebraic set of dimension $\dim_\mathbb{C} O(n,\mathbb{C})=\frac12n(n-1)$, so is noncompact for $n\geq 2$ in the usual (transcendence) topology.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathcal O(2,\mathbb C)$ contains $\pmatrix{\cos(z) & \sin(z)\cr -\sin(z) & \cos(z)\cr}$ for every $z \in \mathbb C$.  Since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are unbounded on $\mathbb C$, $\mathcal O(2,\mathbb C)$ is unbounded and thus not compact.  Similarly for $n > 2$, using  block matrices of the form $\pmatrix{A & 0\cr 0 & I\cr}$ where 
$A = \pmatrix{\cos(z) & \sin(z)\cr -\sin(z) & \cos(z)\cr}$.

Comment: If I use this norm, $||A||^2=tr(AA^t)$ then norm is $\sqrt 2$. How it is unbounded?

Comment: What does it mean by a norm on a nonlinear space? @RîtëshKhåñ

Comment: No, norm of linear space. Why you are talking about non-linear space? @ Arctic Char

Comment: Because $O(n, \mathbb C)$ is not a linear space. @RîtëshKhåñ

Comment: $\|A\|^2 = tr(A A^t)$ does not give a norm on complex matrices: it is not real.  Instead you want $tr(A A^*)$ where $A^*$ is the Hermitian conjugate.  That would make $$\|A\| = \sqrt{2 (|\cos(z)|^2 + |\sin(z)|^2)} = \sqrt{2 \cosh(\text{Im}(2z))}$$

Answer (score 0):

The subset of matrices in $2\times2$ of the form $\displaystyle{1\quad x \choose 0\quad 1}$ is in $GL(2)$ for any $x$ and this set  is closed. If GL(2) were compact this should be compact. But this is clearly not.

Comment: The op has changed the question

Comment: Now my answer is not applicable as the question has changed.